# Instantiating an object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just learning Angular and am trying to work out the best way to instantiate an object.

In my old style of javascript i would do something like this:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    var greeting;

    this.init = function(my_greeting){
        greeting = my_greeting;
    }

    this.get_greeting = function(){
        return greeting;
    }
};

var instance = new MyClass();
instance.init("hello");
console.log(instance.get_greeting());
```

Now I'm struggling to find the best way to achieve the best pattern in angular. What I'm currently doing is this:

```
my_app.factory("MyClass", function(){
    return function(){
        var greeting;

        this.init = function(my_greeting){
            greeting = my_greeting;
        }

        this.get_greeting = function(){
            return greeting;
        }
    }
});

my_app.service("MyService", ["MyClass", function(MyClass){
    var instance = new MyClass();
    instance.init("hello");
}]);
```

Is this the best way of going about this? Is the idea of having the function within a function a bit of an antipattern?

thanks

Comment: Well.. It depends I suppose. A factory is a factory, a javascript class is a javascript class. There's nothing stopping you from using a javascript class in Angular... It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the function of `MyClass`? Who uses it?

Answer (score 0):

A factory provides you with the return value of the function that has ben defined. So instead of returning your constructor, you could simply do this:

```
my_app.factory("MyClass", function(){

  return {
    greeting: '',
    init: function(){
       // ...
    },
    // ...
  }
});
```

And so, you will get an instance of your class to inject wherever you like it. I think that this is the most common usage, because seldom you'll need more than one instance of `myClass`

However, if you need for some reason multiple instances, then your approach is just right. Personally, I like to do things like this when I need to fetch multiple instances:

```
my_app.factory("superService", function(){

    function MyClass(){

    }

    MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
        //...
    };

  return {
    getInstance: function(){
        return new MyClass();
    }
  }
```

});

Or in a similiar way. But as @Patrick pointed out in the comments, it heavily depends on what you are trying to achieve and nothing stops you from applying OO patterns to your Angular application.

For instance, I use a provider which has to be configured with a set of key - value pairs, then creates an instance of a class `Trash` for each such key and provides me with a service that returns each instance:

```
trashModule.provider('Trash',function(){

var module = this;

this.config = {};

this.$get = function(trashInstance){

    var entities = {};

    for(var item in module.config){
        entities[item] = trashInstance.get((module.config[item]));
    }

    return entities;

};

});
```

That way, I have a single service which neatly holds together all the dustbins I need, while being the only place that has to know about the actual class.